# How to Fix: “Ubuntu No Wi-Fi Adapter Found” issue

Tags: command-line

Many Ubuntu users face hardware compatibility problems like being unable to detect a Wi-Fi adapter or unable to detect a graphics card including me.

I tried to use Software Updater but it fails

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This Q is not about software programming. It seems more appropriate for https://askubuntu.com , but it is very vague and doesn't contain anything another reader can test on their system. So, please read their help on what is a good question and provide the needed information.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.